# How sort multiindex dataframe by column value and maintain multiindex structure?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, sorting, multi-index

I have a multiindex (TestName and TestResult.Outcome) dataframe, want to sort descending by a column value and maintain the visual multiindex pair (TestName and TestResult.Outcome). How can I achieve that?

For example, I want to sort desc by column "n * %" for TestResult.Outcome index value "Failed" the following table:

[image]

I want to achieve the following outcome, maintaining the Pass Fail pairs in the indices:
[image]

I tried this:

```
orderedByTotalNxPercentDesc = myDf.sort_values(['TestResult.Outcome','n * %'], ascending=False)
```

but this orders firstly by index values = "Passed" and breaks the Passed Failed index pairs
[image]

Comment: Not sure I understand it correctly, but it makes sense to `groupby` `TestName` if you wish to have the pairs.

Answer (score 1):

This can help you:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

arrays = [np.array(["bar", "bar", "baz", "baz", "foo", "foo", "qux", "qux"]),np.array(["one", "two", "one", "two", "one", "two", "one", "two"])]

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(8, 4), index=arrays)

df.reset_index().groupby(["level_0"]).apply(lambda x: x.sort_values([3], ascending = False)).set_index(['level_0','level_1'])
```

In your case `3` is your column `n * %`, `level_0` is your index `TestName` and `level_1` is your `TestResult.Outcome`.

[image]

Becomes:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the hint, unfortunately it is not what I am looking for. You ordered firstly by level_0, and then within the level_0 index by column 3. This only orders the level_1 "one two" indices within each level_0 index. You can have a another look at my "I want to achive" screenshot. In your example need to order by column 3 first across all level_0 and want to keep level_1 pairs.

Comment: Ah, got it. Will try to follow up.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get what I want by creating a dummy column for sorting:

```
iterables = [["bar", "baz", "foo", "qux"], ["one", "two"]]

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(8, 1), index=arrays)
df.index.names = ['level_0', 'level_1']
df = df.rename(columns={0: "myvalue"}, errors='raise')

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    df.loc[index,'sort_dummy'] = df.loc[(index[0],'two'),'myvalue']

df = df.sort_values(['sort_dummy'], ascending = False)
df
```

Output:

[image]